# Error while declaring a variable inside for-loop along with print statement

Tags: java, for-loop

I was trying to learn how for-loop works, so I made such a code.

```
for(System.out.println("hi"),int i=0;i<5;System.out.println("yo"),i++) 
{
System.out.println("teapot");
}
```

This way I can understand, which part of for-loop is being executed when. But I am getting an error in the first line stating ".class expected". Maybe this simply means, I cannot declare a variable in the first line. So I reworked it, and now it works perfectly.

```
int i;
for(System.out.println("hi"),i=0;i<5;System.out.println("yo"),i++) 
{
System.out.println("teapot");
}
```

But I don't understand why I cannot declare a variable in the first line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax of a [basic for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1) is:

```
BasicForStatement:
  for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) Statement

BasicForStatementNoShortIf:
  for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) StatementNoShortIf

ForInit:
  StatementExpressionList 
  LocalVariableDeclaration
```

In other words: the first bit of the `for` can contain either a list of [statement expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-StatementExpression), or local variable declarations, but not both.

- `System.out.println("hi")` is a statement expression (because it's a method invocation expression);
- `int i=0` is not a statement expression (because it's not an expression);
- `i=0` is a statement expression, because it's an assignment.

Comment: What is "StatementNoShortIf" ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36048981/java-bnf-no-short-if-what-does-this-mean